# Wikilink to a symbolic link in ikiwiki

Tags: symlink, apache-httpd, wiki, ikiwiki

I am running an [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) for my personal use on my laptop via apache2 (os: ubuntu 10.04).

If I want to make a link to a local pdf-file I put the file into my scrdir and use the usual wikilink syntax. However if I put only a symbolic link into the scrdir instead of the actual file, it doesn't work. Is there a way to make that ikiwiki handles symbolic links in this situation?

Comment: What is ikiwiki? Sounds funny.

Comment: @Kevdog777 See http://ikiwiki.info/ ikiwiki is a wiki with git backend. You can just do all the things with the wiki you can do with git..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an Apache configuration issue. Ensure you have [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)`+FollowSymLinks` (or `Options +All`) set for the given directory.

Comment: Also, make sure that the permissions for the symlink's target are such that Apache can access it. That means at the minimum that all directories up to the target must have the x-bit set.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ikiwiki compiling / rendering results in nothing being present in the rendered tree (`destdir` in ikiwiki terms), where a symlink was present in the input tree (`srcdir` in ikiwiki terms).

This can be confirmed easily by looking at the rendered tree in the filesystem.

It does not get as far as the Apache web server getting to see it, so no amount of Apache configuration will help.

Comment: There's a typo: "Sounds like and" should be "Sounds like an"